# Is it normal that most or all rooting apps get so many virus warnings?

Tags: rooting

For example, here are some results from VirusTotal:

- [TowelRoot](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/5aa19d58ccda518979ecec97db9ee7a6a1de606fd661ef9238e65f3b533f170c/analysis/)
- The variants of Framaroot ([1](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/34ba5e97b8ecc97bfb891bdb3306bba6144411c28734f556242ffee6d8948035/analysis/), [2](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/d26016f5df8349f836ec2397903946392c636a0a4cdad30da8da4b58797664d4/analysis/), [3](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/d26016f5df8349f836ec2397903946392c636a0a4cdad30da8da4b58797664d4/analysis/))

Why is that? Can anyone point to a clean rooting app?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's normal. Think about what a rooting app does. It exploits a vulnerability in the operating system to get elevated privileges, and drops a new binary so that it will continue to have those privileges, completely subverting the security of the system. In a way, a rooting app *is* a virus. You certainly wouldn't want to install one by accident, so it's correct that your antivirus should warn about it.

If you want a "clean" method of rooting, the only way is to use the official method, by unlocking your bootloader and using the recovery to root.